# formatting colour for cell and row in excel using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

my requirement highlight the different of those cell to "yellow" and new rows added will be highlight in red colour in excel as a output.

**load1 dataset**

```
StudentID   Visit1      Visit 2     Visit 3     Visit 4
1           16-04-20    23-04-20    30-04-20    07-05-20
2           17-04-20    24-04-20    01-05-20    08-05-20
3           18-04-20    25-04-20    02-05-20    09-05-20
4           19-04-20    26-04-20    03-05-20    10-05-20
5           20-04-20    27-04-20    04-05-20    11-05-20
6           21-04-20    28-04-20    05-05-20    12-05-20
7           22-04-20    29-04-20    06-05-20    13-05-20
8           23-04-20    30-04-20    07-05-20    14-05-20
```

**load2 table**

```
StudentID   Visit1      Visit 2     Visit 3     Visit 4
1           16-04-20    23-04-20    30-04-20    07-05-20
2           17-04-20    24-04-20    01-05-20    08-05-20
3           18-04-20    25-09-20    02-05-20    09-05-20
4           19-04-20    26-04-20    03-06-20    10-05-20
5           20-04-20    27-04-20    04-05-20    11-05-20
6           21-04-20    28-04-20    05-05-20    12-06-20
7           22-04-20    29-08-20    06-05-20    13-05-20
8           23-04-20    30-04-20    07-05-20    14-05-20
9           15-05-20    16-05-20    17-05-20    18-05-20
```

**Output. I am looking for the output in excel in the below format with colours hi-lighted.**

[image]

**I am new to this pandas, I was able to get the different difference at dataframe level. Not at the outputed excel where to format each cell and row with colours.Please help .**

the below are the script i tried to get the difference.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
colour1= pd.read_excel('pandas.xlsx',sheet_name='load1')
colour2= pd.read_excel('pandas.xlsx',sheet_name='load2')
colour_merge=colour1.merge(colour2,left_on='StudentID', right_on='StudentID',how='outer')
colour_merge['Visit1dif']= np.where(colour_merge['Visit1_x']==colour_merge['Visit1_y'],0,1)
colour_merge['Visit2dif']= np.where(colour_merge['Visit 2_x']==colour_merge['Visit 2_y'],0,1)
colour_merge['Visit3dif']= np.where(colour_merge['Visit 3_x']==colour_merge['Visit 3_y'],0,1)
colour_merge['Visit4dif']= np.where(colour_merge['Visit 4_x']==colour_merge['Visit 4_y'],0,1)
colour_merge[['StudentID','Visit1_x','Visit1_y','Visit1dif','Visit 2_x','Visit 2_y','Visit2dif','Visit 3_x','Visit 3_y','Visit3dif','Visit 4_x','Visit 4_y','Visit4dif']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two sheets `load1` and `load2`, and want to and the third one to be displayed in the picture.

In order to add a new sheet, `pandas.ExcelWriter` should be opened in `append` mode and `openpyxl` library is needed along with `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` and `conditional_formatting` functions :

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import xlrd

from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font, NamedStyle, PatternFill, colors
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule, ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule

file = r'C:\\app\\excel\\pandas.xlsx'
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sht = xls.sheet_names()

colour1= pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=sht[0])
colour2= pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=sht[1])
colour_merge = colour1.merge(colour2,left_on='StudentID',right_on='StudentID',how='outer')
colour_merge = colour_merge[['StudentID','Visit 1_x','Visit 1_y','Visit 2_x','Visit 2_y','Visit 3_x','Visit 3_y','Visit 4_x','Visit 4_y']]

l_sid = []
mxc1 = max(colour1['StudentID'])+1
mxc2 = max(colour2['StudentID'])+1
for j in range(min(mxc1,mxc2),max(mxc1,mxc2)):
    l_sid.append(j+1)

writer_args = { 'path': file, 'mode': 'a', 'engine': 'openpyxl'}

with pd.ExcelWriter(**writer_args) as xlsx:
    colour_merge.to_excel(xlsx, 'load3', index=False)
    ws = xlsx.sheets['load3']
    mxc= ws.max_column


    title_row = '1'

    yellow = PatternFill(bgColor=colors.YELLOW)
    red    = PatternFill(bgColor=colors.RED)    
    i=1    
    while i <= mxc*2:
        l_col = []
        l_col.append(chr(i+65))
        l_col.append(chr(i+65+1))

        for j in range(2,mxc+1):
            for k in l_col:
                if j not in l_sid:
                    ws.conditional_formatting.add(k+str(j), FormulaRule(formula=[l_col[0]+'$'+str(j)+'<>'+l_col[1]+'$'+str(j)], stopIfTrue=True, fill=yellow))

        i+=2


    r = Rule(type="expression", dxf=DifferentialStyle(fill=red), stopIfTrue=False)
    r.formula = ['1=1']

    while l_sid:
        el=l_sid.pop(-1)        
        ws.conditional_formatting.add('A'+str(el)+':'+chr(64+mxc)+str(el), r) 


xlsx.save()
```

Comment: Thanks barbaros.I am seeing now, it is selecting the entire row as yellow for the difference of the date. 
can you tweak the code to higlight only the difference of those cell only in yellow colour.

Comment: Hi @Rod , you're welcome. The code looks for each column pairs whether they're different, if so, paints to yellow in the first step. In the second step, paints the extra row(s) to red if one of the sheets has more row(s) than the other one.

Comment: Thanks for your response, its highlighting the entire row which i observed. only those different of those cell should be paint to yello.  For Red it is fine.
Hope you understood what i mean. Refer the output which i shown in my orginal post.

Comment: [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArBB-CANDExfgmnTtOjy9Aq395wN) is the concerned file I used with the above code @Rod. You can retry by removing the sheet `load3`, the code will automatically add this sheet. I derived the column titles for `load1` and `load2` sheets from your code.

Comment: Thanks barbaros. Sorry for the delay response. It has work as expected. Can you PM your personal email address ? thanks.

Comment: you're welcome, nevermind @Rod . barbaros_ozhan@yahoo.com